# Over allocation of slots in BigQuery project

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been using BigQuery in the on-demand pricing model. For some complex queries I have seen from the Stackdriver report that BigQuery over allocates slots beyond the 2,000 mark, e.g. I have seen up to 7,000 slots allocated in the same project over several minutes. It did not go beyond this number. I am wondering how to interpret these figures.

Does BigQuery allocate additional (otherwise) idle slots if there is spare capacity in Google data centres?

The 2,000 slot limit does not seem to be a hard limit, correct?

When I hit 7,000 slots I saw a slowdown of queries. Is this when some sort of resource management kicks in that serialises the queries (FIFO) or FAIRly allocates resources.

I am curious if this over allocation also happen for flat rate pricing?

Comment: I don't have time to write a complete answer, but the 7000 allocated slots shown in StackDriver is an artifact of how the sampling works; it doesn't actually indicate that more than 2000 slots were in use at one point. Scheduling is fair rather than FIFO.

Comment: ok. I am struggling with the usefulness of the Stackdriver report information then. At best it is not useful at worst misleading. Maybe I am missing something but right now I find it hard to interpret the Stackdriver report and how the info could be useful.

Comment: Which stackdriver metric are you looking at? It is possible that your project has more than 2000 slots allocated to it if you're concurrently running load and/or export jobs (2k for query + x for other job types). Those run in a public pool [1] so might skew your slots allocated metric. I would try breaking down the metric by job type to confirm that you're actually seeing > 2k slots for your queries.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#metrics